# What advantages/disadvantages does a Darksaber have over a lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, lightsaber

Does the darksaber that Pre Viszla owned have any advantages/disadvantages to a traditional lightsaber? I've never seen it deflect blaster bolts, but that's because Viszla's reflexes aren't fast enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**None. The [Darksaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber_%28lightsaber%29) does not seem to have any unique powers.**

- It is just an ancient Lightsaber with a unique color (black) and shape (blade-like).

[image]

- It doesn't appear to have any other properties besides a distinctive hum and the ability to block other lightsabers.
- Since Pre Viszla is not a Jedi, he was unable to use it to perform any other Jedi maneuvers.
- Despite the claim that only Jedi could use a lightsaber effectively, Pre Viszla seemed quite capable in his battle against Darth Maul.

Comment: Jedis are incredibly under-powered in this serie, that's why he was able to fight Maul.

Comment: That was not my point. I was under the impression, non-Jedi wouldn't or couldn't use light-sabers due to an inherent difficulty of a weightless blade or gyroscopic balance issues or something to that effect, making them far more dangerous to the user than to their target. Pre Viszla didn't seem to have that difficulty at all. Against anyone other than a force-user, I would have counted on a easy victory.

Comment: General Grievous was also quite capable with a lightsaber or two (or four!), just as more evidence that it was *not* strictly limited to Jedi.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze I'm afraid you're mistakened. That is now Legends. The plasma blade carries weight now. Trained non-sensitives can use a lightsaber - a Force user is just capable of integrating the Force into their moves. The reason lightsabers aren't in common usage (when not contraband) is because only Force sensitives can assemble them: Calibration of a Kyber crystal's position & orientation must be perfected in relation to its molecular matrix to not blow itself up. A lightsaber is more dangerous to a non-sensitive attempting assembly rather than actual usage.

Comment: imo a darksaber is simply a lightkatana or something similar. A "laser sword" like any other, but a katana version.