# Are there any other weapons designed using lightsaber technology?

Tags: star-wars, weapon

I know Darth Maul used a lightsaber staff which was basically two lightsabers end to end.

I had thought that lightsaber nunchaku would be amazing, but the fact that you'd rather quickly lose your own hand during a change over would be problematic!!

So are there any other weapons designed using this technology?

Comment: The Darth Bane series explains the lightsaber process very well and the benefits of each type. I would highly recommend reading them as they are some of my favourite Star Wars novels

Comment: Just a note, nunchaku would be very problematic as a light-sabre-type weapon as either side is meant to be alternatively used as the "handle". Sometimes both sides being handled at once with hands, arms, etc. for standard technique.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I realize that, this is why I mentioned you'd loose your own hand if you tried to use them!

Comment: Mr Welch's list #1012: Note to self: Lightsaberchucks...BAD IDEA

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lumiya used a [Lightwhip](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightwhip), which was same technology.

"Related" links section on Wookieepedia includes:

Crossguard lightsaber · Curved-hilt lightsaber · Darksaber · Dual-phase lightsaber · Double-bladed lightsaber · Lightclub · Lightfoil · Lightwhip · Long-handle lightsaber · Lightsaber pike · Paired lightsabers · Protosaber · Sabercane · Lightsaber shoto / Guard shoto

Comment: Nice. Also on that link are Lightsaber pike, Shoto, and Lightclub!

Answer (score 9):

The unfinished, but canon, *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* arc *[Crystal Crisis on Utapau](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Clone_Wars_Legacy#Crystal_Crisis_on_Utapau)* features a giant green kyber crystal.

Yoda mentions how giant kyber crystals were used in ancient super-weapons:

> Long ago in forgotten times when the Sith and Jedi fought for control of the galaxy, weapons there were of unimaginable power. Always at their heart a kyber crystal was.

It's also heavily implied that a similar crystal was later used in the Death Star. The canon novel *Tarkin* confirms this.

> The designers are also debating the optimum configuration for the Kyber crystal assembly.

[image: Giant crystal]

Additionally, The First Order Star Destroyer *[Finalizer](https://www.starwars.com/databank/finalizer)*, and possibly other First Order Star Destroyers used kyber crystals in their turbolasers.

> Her turbolasers are more powerful and faster to recharge than Imperial-era weapons, a product of kyber crystals harvested in the Unknown Regions.

Comment: The Death Star is just a big lightsaber? That's awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is. Darksaber.
[image: Darksaber]
[image: Darksaber held by Pre Vizsla]

Currently, it is owned by Darth Maul who won it from Pre Vizsla (*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*).

Comment: Is this a lightsaber using a black crystal?

Comment: @AidanO - See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31074/what-advantages-disadvantages-does-a-darksaber-have-over-a-lightsaber

Comment: didn't Maul die before the Clone Wars started?

Comment: @Suman No. He survived when Kenobi cut him into two parts. He returned during The Clone Wars.

Comment: Maul was also a recurring character in Rebels, until his death (by Kenobi) in S3E20 "Twin Suns"

Answer (score 4):

**The Death Star's super laser was developed with Lightsaber technology, along with an ancient array of weapons of mass destruction.**

> According to legend, the ancient Sith used massive kyber crystals to create superweapons; during the Clone Wars, the Geonosians revived the superlaser design. [starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/death-star-superlaser)

This is a new addition to Disney Canon, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Star Wars Battlefront 2 there is a downloadable character that wields lightsaber nunchucks. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9ENrwMDKQQ).

Comment: A photo would be great!

Comment: would love to see that!