# Are there non-weapon items in the Star Wars universe based on lightsaber technology?

Tags: star-wars

After mis-reading this question: [Are there any other weapons designed using lightsaber technology?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31429/are-there-any-other-weapons-designed-using-lightsaber-technology) I found myself wondering if there are other non-weapon items such as tools that utilize lightsaber technology.

*Example: the lightsaber bread knife*

[image]

Comment: The "[Lightsaber bread knife!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t5qs1.jpg)" : *This toast bread while you're slicing it.*

Comment: Ah yes, the best thing since sliced bread. As featured in the 2005 film _The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy_.

Comment: By 'technology', if you mean 'uses the same crystals', there are a number of lightsaber-used crystals that get used in other gear and for other uses.

Comment: I guess since crystals are a large part of the tech behind lightsabers, yeah, that would be included but that's not exclusively what I mean.  @Neil - thanks for the link.  I didn't realize crystals were altered with the force by the creator of the blade.

Comment: @emachine I didn't mean to come across as as smart-alec.  My point was simply that nobody other than jedis and siths could make them, and so logically, you couldn't expect that they would have applied that technology to other things since that hardly seems important to them.  It'd be like asking if the Amish ever used their quilt-making ability to make a rockin' car seat cover.

Comment: @Neil Not Smart-alec-y at all, relevant and valid point. If I could upvote your comment I would.

Comment: @Neil:  http://amishcountrytreasures.tictail.com/product/quilted-toilet-seat-cover-and-tank-topper-unique    not for a car, but a seat cover

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'm sure you could also use a lightsaber to chop wood, but I'm pretty sure it would end up in immediate body dismemberment.  [See chart for details.](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GL2qG27MejU/ULls-8TSS2I/AAAAAAACH0c/M7VagkCCqKs/w506-h330/lightsaber.jpg)

Comment: I really want a bread knife like that now, really really want one

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interesting question.  The first lightsabers (then known as forcesabers) could only be made with an intense meditation ritual in which several "Je'daiis" created a strong permanent field around the beam of plasma used as the blade.  Without this field, the plasma blade would be infinitely long or would expand out in all directions.  It seems in the Star Wars universe that the only way to tame a beam of plasma is with the Force.  I'm going to say no.  Only the Jedi/Sith have this type of technology because no force master is going to sit around making plasma knives and plasma toasters.

Comment: This seems to sum up a couple of the comments.  I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Infinite lightsaber - http://xkcd.com/1433/

Comment: In the Expanded Universe, it seems there are other plasma-based cutting devices.  I'm rereading Timothy Zahn's *Heir to the Empire*; the mole miners which feature prominently in the Imperial raid on Sluis Van are described as having plasma jets, which turn out to be pretty effective at cutting through... things.  The mole miners seem to be ordinary (if obscure) industrial machines, and there's no mention of Jedi being involved in their production.

Comment: This seems to no longer be true with the new Star Wars movie as a non-force user is able to wield a lightsaber without catastrophe ensuing

Comment: What about the lightsaber crystals?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg No need to invoke Episode VII. Even Episode IV and V contain instances of untrained people wielding lightsabers. (Plus, in the EU there were mass-produced lightsabers at some point. Young Jedi Knights series, iirc.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are [laser scalpels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Laser_scalpel) in the Star Wars universe:

[image: A laser scalpel]

Don’t be fooled by the name. It’s *probably* not an actual laser being shot out of the hilt, but rather similar plasma technology to that of a lightsaber (“laser swords”).
Laser scalpels were used for medical purposes and weren’t used as weapons.

Answer (score 1):

first of all this is merely speculative,
in Episode 1, during the battle between Darth Maul and Qui-Gon, there are a series of red barriers, they switch on and off in a similar way and make a similar noise when a light saber hits them. they could use a similar technology

Comment: That's `Ray Shield`...

Comment: damn! they should take my geek card from me

Comment: Who is Ray Shield? He seems to pop up all over the place.