# Are shields in the Star Wars universe the same technology as Lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars

The Gungans had some impressive shield technology that I presume The Empire/Galactic Republic had similar sorts of technology.

When using these shields in the Battle of Naboo in *The Phantom Menance*, the Gungans had a massive encompassing shield that absorbed blasts from the Trade Federation. They also had personal hand-held mobile shields for some of their troops that also reflected energy blasts from Trade Federation Droids.

Thus back to the question, are shields in the *Star Wars* universe the same technology as Lightsabers or somewhat along the same foundation/theory as Lightsabers ?

Comment: Related: [Are there non-weapon items in the Star Wars universe based on lightsaber technology?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31444/are-there-non-weapon-items-in-the-star-wars-universe-based-on-lightsaber-technol)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A lightsaber consisted of [pure plasma forced into shape by a force field](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber). In contrast, a [personal shield](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Personal_energy_shield) (like those the Gungan warriors used) consisted of a force field that shields the user from blaster fire (or other types of weapons in more advanced versions).

Therefore we can say that lightsabers and shields share the force field tech, but use it in a different way — in the shield the force field is the main component, while in a lightsaber it "holds" the main component which is plasma.

Comment: Leave a comment when you downvote - so I know what I did wrong and can eventually improve!